# string index out of range in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I want to find how many times an character repeated in a word for example: how many times the 'l' repeated in the "Hello". but it drops me this error:

> IndexError: string index out of range

And my code:

```
def fin(x,lst):
   if x == '':
      return 0
   if lst[0] == x:
      return 1+ fin(x,lst[1:])
   else:
      return fin(x,lst[1:])
```

Comment: how many items in lst when this error occurs? Maybe you had only 1 item, and the lst[1:] slicing generated this error

Comment: Hint: what happens if I call `fin("X", "")`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are pre-written functions in python to do this for you.  But if you're doing this for the sake of education...

You have the wrong stop condition, you should be checking if the `lst` is empty, not `x`